# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping for GET /DemoSpringMaven/add

Tags: spring, maven

When i try to run this project i received following error
"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /DemoSpringMaven/add".

**Error**

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /DemoSpringMaven/add
```

**Web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>frontcontroller</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>frontcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**WEB-INF/frontcontroller-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.fazaal"></context:component-scan>


</beans>
```

**Controller/AddController.java**

```
    package com.fazaal;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class AddController {

        @RequestMapping("/add")
        public void add() {
            System.out.println("I am Here!");
        }

}
```

Comment: You should try to phrase a question and put your code in the question instead of image links.

Comment: as you told i edited my quection

Answer (score 0):

First, all these web.xml, servlets' XML configurations, manual setting of chains - this is the last age, sorry. Spring hid all these configurations inside own framework and you can use just very convenient annotations. One application class, one configuration class - and the web application works! And if you are a newbie in Spring, Spring MVC or JSP/Servlets, or you need to start your application ASAP, or you need a platform from which you want to start the framework learning, just use Spring Boot.

Second, if you want to leave your configuration ... how will MVC know about mapping `/DemoSpringMaven/add`? You specified just `/add`. Add full mapping or add global controller @RequestMapping("/DemoSpringMaven").

Answer (score 0):

Try this servlet mapping:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Also the method should have @ResponseBody before it (probably this it the source of the issue):

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public void add() {
        System.out.println("I am Here!");
    }
```

But as Dmitry Ionash said, this is really old way how to build Spring web applications. Try Spring Boot: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/